# AWS : Play Custom Sound When Push Messages are received

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have implemented Amazon Web Service(AWS) for notification messages in my app, I am able to send message from Amazon SNS Server successfully.

Now i want to implement **default/custom** sound, when any messages are received from AWS.

In Amazon SNS Server there are two options fro sending pus messages, those are Raw and JSON. I am using Raw Message Format.

```
{
     "aps":{
        "badge":0,
        "alert":"APNS test",
        "sound":"default"
      },
}
```

by above format i m getting same format as push notification in my app.

**If i use JSON Message Format**

I m getting in Amazon SNS Page that -

> Invalid parameter: Message Structure - JSON message body failed to
>   parse (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidParameter; Request ID: b34a

Any One could tell tell how to send sound default/custom by using AWS Notification.

Answer (score 1):

Try as bellow

Please make sure to change the JSON according to your need

```
{
  "aps" : {
  "category" : "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
    "alert" : {
       "body" : "Acme message received from Johnny Appleseed",
       "action-loc-key" : "VIEW"
    },
    "badge" : 3,
    "sound" : "chime.aiff"
  },
  "acme-account" : "jane.appleseed@apple.com",
  "acme-message" : "message123456"
 }
```

Comment: stil getting same error , when i pass ur json paylod to AWS SNS Dashboard in

Comment: did your notification worked when you set default notification sound?

Comment: no, when i just send Raw message from SNS Dashboard, i get push message, but not default/custom sound i m not able to get those

Comment: when you get push message to your device , cant you hear any sound ?

Comment: use the sound as default.wav